# Error HTTP 0x8007000d en IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

quisiera saber porqué me genera éste error, pues llevo unos días intentando hacer una publicación (despliegue) en ASP.NetCore, pero al pasarlo al IIS me genera este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que entiendo, el error está en el web.config, pero no sé cómo leer un web.config y no sé muy bien cómo funciona.

Adjunto también el web.config por si lo necesitan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <!-- When deploying on Azure, make sure that "dotnet" is installed and the path to it is registered in the PATH environment variable or specify the full path to it -->
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="23:00:00" processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Nop.Web.dll" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" startupTimeLimit="3600">
      <environmentVariables />
    </aspNetCore>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <!-- Protects against XSS injections. ref.: https://www.veracode.com/blog/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers/ -->
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <!-- Protects against Clickjacking attacks. ref.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22105445/1233379 -->
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <!-- Protects against MIME-type confusion attack. ref.: https://www.veracode.com/blog/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers/ -->
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <!-- Protects against Clickjacking attacks. ref.: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet -->
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" />
        <!-- CSP modern XSS directive-based defence, used since 2014. ref.: http://content-security-policy.com/ -->
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; connect-src *; font-src *; frame-src *; img-src * data:; media-src *; object-src *; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';" />
        <!-- Prevents from leaking referrer data over insecure connections. ref.: https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-referrer-policy/ -->
        <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="strict-origin" />
        <!--Feature-Policy is a new header that allows a site to control which features and APIs can be used in the browser. ref.: https://wicg.github.io/feature-policy/ -->
        <add name="Feature-Policy" value="accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; payment *; usb 'none'" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 4f1f649c-1020-45be-a487-f416d9297ff3-->
```

De ante mano muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general este problema se asocia a una incorrecta creacion del `web site` en el `IIS`

No se si estas creandolo dentro del `Default Web Site` el cual se asocia al puerto 80, o si creas un nuevo sitio con un puerto diferente

[Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

si analizamos desde el titulo "IIS configuration" observaras que indica como habilitar el `IIS` en el servidor asi como definir el `web site`

Es muy importante indicar correctamente el `Application Pool` asociado al sitio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]